# How to visualize 3D volume?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, volume-rendering

I had tried the following demo code in Matlab. I'm using Matlab 2018b

```
load('spiralVol.mat');
h = volshow(spiralVol);
```

But I'm getting a black screen.imshow() is working properly. Is it related to opengl? i tried opengl software and opengl hardware

Is it a bug in matlab 2018b? or is it related to my system configuration

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this "black screen".  I'm getting this figure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TAMP.png.  Using MATLAB R2018b.

Comment: imshow() is working properly.is it related to opengl

Comment: Could it just be a slow machine that is taking forever to render?

Comment: You should probably contact MATLAB support for things like this (or your campus license administrator if you're using a campus license).

Comment: @MadPhysicist  core i3 4gb ram is my system configuration

Comment: @CrisLuengo how to contact matlab?

Comment: Go to mathworks.com, click on "Support" along the top of the page, then "Contact Support", that leads to this page: https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html

Answer (score 0):

The black screen is sometimes an issue due to bad graphics driver. Try updating the driver to its latest version.

Alternately, Image Processing Toolbox has a 'VolumeViewerUseHardware' preference setting which tells it not to use the graphics card while rendering. Try setting it to false and see if it resolves the issue:
[iptsetpref](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/iptsetpref.html)

Comment: how to update driver?i also didnt understand the second option